# css div dynamic issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm learning CSS. I am doing one small task..

I had one centre box, when its width , height  changes, all  its header, footer, left-sidebar, right-sidebar also should change accordingly!

I am doing something wrong. please find my code below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>

 <script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

 <script>
        var modified_width, modified_height;

        function set_width_height(width,height){
            var width_factor=width/1024;
            var height_factor=height/768;
            var scale_factor=(width_factor>height_factor)?width_factor: height_factor;
            modified_width=width*scale_factor;
            modified_height=height*scale_factor;
            return {width:modified_width, height:modified_height};
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
             set_width_height(800,480)
    /*      var width2 = 1024 - modified_width;
            var height2 = 768 - modified_height;*/
            $("#id6").css({'width':modified_width, 'height':modified_height});
/*
            $("#id6").css("width",modified_width);
            $("#id6").css("height",modified_height);*/

        //  alert(modified_width)

            width1 = (1024 - modified_width)/2;
            height1 = (768 - modified_height)/2;
            $("#id2").css("width",width1);
            $("#id4").css("width",width1);
            $("#id3").css("height",height1);
            $("#id5").css("height",height1);
        })
 </script>
    <style>
    .inc {
        position:absolute;
        border:1px solid white; 
    }

        #id1{
            width:1024px;
            height:768px;
        }

        #id2{
            left:0;
            top:0;
            bottom:0;
            width:20%;
            height:100%;
            background:red;
        }
        #id3{
            top:0;
            left:20%;
            width:60%;
            height:15%;
            background:pink;
        }
        #id4{
            right:0;
            top:0;
            bottom:0;
            width:20%;
            background:green;
        }
        #id5{
            bottom:0;
            left:20%;
            height:15%;
            width:60%;
            background:yellow;
        }
        #id6{
            top:25%;            
            left:25%;
            width:60%;
            height:70%;         
            background:black;
        }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="id1" class="mainc">
            <div id="id2" class="inc" >
B
            </div>

        <div id="id3"  class="inc" >
D
            </div>
            <div id="id4"  class="inc">
C
            </div>
            <div id="id5"  class="inc">
E
            </div>
            <div id="id6"  class="inc">
F
            </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qQSBH/)

Comment: "I am learning..." - "please fix" -> bad match.

Comment: @user1708762 PLEASE find Jsfiddle link above..

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why you need all that javascript to get the layout you want. If you really want to learn CSS you will find using css display: table can get you the layout you are looking for. Have a look at my fiddle to get you off in the right direction.

```
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ben1/84Zgs/